# How to add html before a specific form?

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I am trying to add some custom html to my form.

My `admin.py` is

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Test', {'fields': ('description', 'total_price'),})
    )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Always add (piece of code) what you have done so far. It will be easier to understand exact problem and to provide answer.

Comment: Hello @d.coder. I edited the post. I only want to put some html before these fields, I've already search for a command but no success...